# How to store double - endian independent

Tags: c++, c, interop, endianness

Despite the fact that big-endian computers are not very widely used, I want to store the double datatype in an independant format.

For `int` (or any integral type), this is really simple, since bit shifts make that very convenient.

```
int number;
int size=sizeof(number);
char bytes[size];

for (int i=0; i<size; ++i)
    bytes[size-1-i] = (number >> 8*i) & 0xFF;
```

This code snipet stores the number in big endian format, despite the machine it is being run on. **What is the most elegant way** to do this for double?

Comment: With floating point you need to not only worry about endianness but also format. Can you safely assume IEEE 754 format?

Comment: Yes, let's say so :) Thanks for the remark.

Comment: BTW, for your `int` case, it'd be simpler to do `(number >> (8 * i)) & 0xFF`.

Comment: Note, "char" may different size than 8 bits. std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::digits

Comment: It is at least 8, so in this case this doesn't affect us. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

The best way for portability and taking format into account, is serializing/deserializing the mantissa and the exponent separately. For that you can use the frexp()/ldexp() functions.

For example, to serialize:

```
int exp;
unsigned long long mant;

mant = (unsigned long long)(ULLONG_MAX * frexp(number, &exp));

// then serialize exp and mant.
```

And then to deserialize:

```
// deserialize to exp and mant.

double result = ldexp ((double)mant / ULLONG_MAX, exp);
```

Comment: Really good idea, and might help future visitors. But in my case, the the output format is already agreed upon. It is double precision IEE 754. +1

Answer (score 6):

The elegant thing to do is to limit the endianness problem to as small a scope as possible.  That narrow scope is the I/O boundary between your program and the outside world. For example, the functions that send binary data to / receive binary data from some other application need to be aware of the endian problem, as do the functions that write binary data to / read binary data from some data file. Make those interfaces cognizant of the representation problem.

Make everything else blissfully ignorant of the problem. Use the local representation everywhere else. Represent a double precision floating point number as a `double` rather than an array of 8 bytes, represent a 32 bit integer as an `int` or `int32_t` rather than an array of 4 bytes, et cetera. Dealing with the endianness problem throughout your code is going to make your code bloated, error prone, and ugly.

Comment: True, but the elegance problem exists also on i/o <-> native interface.

Comment: I couldn't have said it better, Aki :). I am already doing that.

Answer (score 1):

The same. Any numeric object, including double, is eventually several bytes which are interpreted in a specific order according to endianness. So if you revert the order of the bytes you'll get exactly the same value in the reversed endianness.

Comment: Yes, that is in the core of the endianness problem. How does this help me?

Comment: No, because the compiler complains that `>>` is not a valid operation on a double.

Comment: @icepack: I don't think so. (double >> 8) doesn't work as well as (integer >> 8)

Comment: @icepack: can't be cast. That causes type conversion. You mean type punning, which has to be done through memory.

Comment: What's the problem with type conversion? `long long` is big enough to hold the `double`.

Comment: That is not a guarantee. Long long is not necessarily big enough to hold the double. I have already tried your idea with `reinterpet_cast<>`, but I got a warning.

Comment: In your case it is (unless your C++ compiler is pre-C++11)

Comment: Anyway, AkiSuihkonen proposal below is the most elegant for both integers, doubles and any other type since it doesn't depend on shifts and relies exclusively on bytes order - thus no compiler warnings etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
 char *src_data;
 char *dst_data;

 for (i=0;i<N*sizeof(double);i++) *dst_data++=src_data[i ^ mask];
 // where mask = 7, if native == low endian
 // mask = 0, if native = big_endian
```

The elegance lies in `mask` which handles also `short` and `int` types: it's `sizeof(elem)-1` if the target and source endianness differ.

Comment: Then one needs to find out the endianness e.g. by storing 1.0 into memory and checking which byte contains 7f.

Answer (score 0):

Not very portable and standards violating, but something like this:

```
std::array<unsigned char, 8> serialize_double( double const* d )
{
  std::array<unsigned char, 8> retval;
  char const* begin = reinterpret_cast<char const*>(d);
  char const* end = begin + sizeof(double);
  union 
  {
    uint8  i8s[8];
    uint16 i16s[4];
    uint32 i32s[2];
    uint64 i64s;
  } u;
  u.i64s = 0x0001020304050607ull; // one byte order
 //  u.i64s = 0x0706050403020100ull; // the other byte order

  for (size_t index = 0; index < 8; ++index)
  {
    retval[ u.i8s[index] ] = begin[index];
  }
  return retval;
}
```

might handle a platform with 8 bit chars, 8 byte doubles, and any crazy-ass byte ordering (ie, big endian in words but little endian between words for 64 bit values, for example).

Now, this doesn't cover the endianness of doubles being different than that of 64 bit ints.

An easier approach might be to cast your double into a 64 bit unsigned value, then output that as you would any other int.

Answer (score 0):

```
void reverse_endian(double number, char (&bytes)[sizeof(double)])
{
    const int size=sizeof(number);
    memcpy(bytes, &number, size);
    for (int i=0; i<size/2; ++i)
        std::swap(bytes[i], bytes[size-i-1]);
}
```